# Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Then prove that $Ha$ or $aH$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $a\in H.$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have just tried as follows:

Let $Ha$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Then, $Ha=H$ $\implies ~a\in Ha$.
In converse part i need to show that $Ha=H.$
please correct me if i am wrong and i need your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: (a) When you show "$Ha$ is a subgroup $\Rightarrow a\in H$," you need to conclude with "$a\in H$." What you concluded instead was $a\in Ha$ though (which is true of all cosets regardless of whether or not they're a subgroup). (b) You're trying to show that $xy^{-1}\in Ha$ for any two elements $x,y\in Ha$. Instead what you showed was that if $b\in Ha$ then $ba^{-1}\in H$ (which, again, is a thing that's true of *any* coset).

Comment: In conclusion, you haven't shown anything at all beyond the fact that $Ha$ is a coset.

Comment: @anon you are right. I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you're not proving anything useful.

Hint: If $Ha$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $e\in Ha$. This should also give an idea for the converse.